# Put Tableview Cells in Sections Alphabetically- Swift 3 and Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to load data into tableview cells, and here is the structure of my data.

```
struct postStruct {
    let title : String!
    let author : String!
    let bookRefCode : String!
    let imageDownloadString : String!
    let status : String!
    let reserved : String!
    let category : String!
    let dueDate : String!
}
```

Now I have the posts sorted alphabetically using

```
 self.posts.sort(by: { $0.title < $1.title })
```

but I do not know how to place the cells that start with A in a section "A", and "B", and so on.

```
class DirectoryTableView: UITableViewController {

    var posts = [postStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Books").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
    snapshot in

    var snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let title = snapshotValue!["title"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let author = snapshotValue!["author"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let bookRefCode = snapshotValue!["bookRefCode"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let status = snapshotValue!["status"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let reserved = snapshotValue!["reserved"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let category = snapshotValue!["category"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let dueDate = snapshotValue!["dueDate"] as? String
    snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


        self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, author: author, bookRefCode: bookRefCode, status: status, reserved: reserved, category: category, dueDate: dueDate) , at: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    })



     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

     }




      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].author

    let label3 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    label3.text = posts[indexPath.row].bookRefCode

    let label4 = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    label4.text = posts[indexPath.row].status

    let label5 = cell?.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel
    label5.text = posts[indexPath.row].category

    let image1 = cell?.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
    image1.text = posts[indexPath.row].imageDownloadString

    let label6 = cell?.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
    label6.text = posts[indexPath.row].reserved

    let label9 = cell?.viewWithTag(9) as! UILabel
    label9.text = posts[indexPath.row].dueDate

    return cell!

}
```

Any ideas, please help! I have tried to sort them with different methods, but I'm confused!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a new structure to save your posts grouped by it's first title letter: `let postsAlphabetically: [String:[Post]]`

You didn't specify the Swift version, so assuming you'll migrate to Swift 4, you can sort the data and group it using a single line:

```
let postsAlphabetically = Dictionary(grouping: self.posts) { $0.title.first! }
// E.g: ["A" : ["A book", "Another book"], "B" : ["Blue Book", "Black Book"]]
```

Later on, you'll use `postsAlphabetically` instead of `self.posts` in your `cellForRowAt` method.

P.S: Type names in Swift are written in upper camel case (`PostSimple` not `postSimple`). And the type itself is omitted (`Author` instead of `AuthorClass`).